# connect argument is undefined under middleware function

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-connect

I have `connect` configuration for - [grunt-contrib-connect](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect)

```
 connect: {
     options: {
         ...
     },
     proxies: [{...
     }],
     livereload: {
         options: {
             base: gruntTargetPath,
             open: true,
             middleware: function(connect, options, middlewares) {
                 return [
                     ...,
                     connect.static('.tmp'),
                     connect().use('/bower_components', connect.static('./bower_components')),
                     connect.static(config.app)
                 ];
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

When I execute on bash - `grunt connect:livereload` , it prompts -

```
 Warning: undefined is not a function Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

(it's regarding to the `connect` argument , I checked it) .

How to pass this argument correctly ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're calling connect rather than referencing it here:

`connect().use`

Should be `connect.use`

**Update**

Looking at the documentation, the middleware function should return an array of functions with the signature `(req, res, next)` but currently you're passing an array of return values from the `use` and `static` methods which could be anything.

Their example inserts functions into the middlewars array and then return it:

```
middlewares.unshift(function(req, res, next) {
            if (req.url !== '/hello/world') return next();

            res.end('Hello, world from port #' + options.port + '!');
          });

          return middlewares;
```

If you want to stick with your current approach of returning an array literal, make sure each array item is a function with the signature expected:

```
[...,
function (req, res, next) { connect.static('.tmp'); },
function (req, res, next) { connect.use('/bower_components', connect.static('./bower_components')); },
...]
```

Comment: no , it gives the same error for any `connect` referal

Comment: I think I see the issue. Will amend my answer.

Comment: I've added a new answer @URL87